# ${2}^{p}+{3}^{p}={a}^{n}$ , then n=1 for any p ?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there an integer $m\geq 1$ such that $2^m+3^m$ is a perfect power?

Comment: The question is unclear (what is quantified how) and (at least the way it is phrased) it is not clear to me that this is a research level question.
Please reformulate to explain what exactly you are asking.

Comment: I found the question perfectly clear actually:  is there an integer $m \ge 1$ such that $2^m + 3^m$ is a perfect power? A quick numerical check gives no examples for $1 \le m \le 50000$.

Comment: David, yes, that seems like a plausible guess! But I'd still love if the original poster could clarify the question / quantization

Comment: For example, does the use of letter $p$ mean a prime?

Comment: Hi i'm the poster. Sorry i stated the question in a lax way. The question is exactly as DL understand it.

Comment: It is proved n=1 for any prime p, or more precisely for {p}={2n+1}-{4m+15}-{4m+5}. 

Comment: There is a theorem (by Zsigmondy?) about factors of integers of the form a^p + b^p which might limit the choices for n when p is composite and has an odd factor.  The remaining case might be handled using what is known about Generalized Fermat numbers.  Gerhard "Email Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.06.27 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really wanted to prove this (and I'm afraid that I'm not sure why you would), you could invoke a Theorem of Darmon and Merel for $n=2$ and $3$, check that there are no solutions with $p \leq 5$, say, and then write down the usual $(n,n,n)$ Frey curve, assuming $n \geq 5$ is prime (which leads to a weight $2$, level $6$ cuspidal newform and hence the desired contradiction).

Of course, this is an absurdly big hammer for such a problem and likely something {\it much} simpler works.

Comment: Using my notations: in that paper they assumed $p\geq 7$ is prime, NOT n (which is the exponent of $a$!). Are you sure you didn't mix the notations up?

Comment: I think Mike did not mix the notation up. What he says is that the paper by Darmon and Merel implies that there are no solutions to your equation with $n=2$ and $n=3$. He then goes on to suggest that it suffices to consider $n$ prime (this is obvious: if $n$ is not prime, say $n=q\cdot m$, then rewrite $a^n$ as $(a^m)^q$), and then proposes a solution involving a Frey curve (which I don't claim to understand, as I don't know anything about Frey curves ;).

Comment: The Frey curve corresponds to 
$$
2^p \cdot 1^n + 3^p \cdot 1^n = a^n.
$$
The ``machinery'' works for prime $n \geq 5$ in this case. Of course, it would work equally well for 
$$
2^p+3^q=a^n
$$
with $p \geq 4$.

Comment: Thanks! And to quote Gjergji Zaimi:"...(this problem) would amount to proving an effective version of Zsigmondy's theorem (where there is a Zsigmondy prime of exponent 1), which is at least as hard as FLT... I believe there are no simpler approaches"

Answer (score 0):

By the Fermat theorem: n is not divisible by p.

Comment: Probably the case (2,3) is far easier than Wiles.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to see a post by Gjergji Zaimi on this question.  My guess is he deleted whatever he might have had, from which I had hoped to learn something.  So I will post a start of an elementary approach in the hopes that he or someone else will finish it.

Consider the case that p is an odd positive integer.  Then a must be a multiple of 5, and either n is one, or else 2^p + 3^p is a multiple of 25, in which case p must be an odd multiple of 5 by considering the sum mod 25.  So in this case a^n is a multiple of 3025 if n is not 1.  This can probably be refined by looking at 2^p + 3^p mod 125, and hopefully considerations mod 11 may finish it off.

Now assume p=2q for some positive integer q.  If n were even we could represent 3^p by
(a  - 2^q)(a+2^q), which would give 3^p = 2^(q+1) + 1, which is not solvable in integers p and q.  So n must be odd, a^n must be 1 mod 8 for p sufficiently large, and so must a if n is not 1.  Again, more work needs to be done here.  It looks plausible to me that n must be 1 if a is an integer.

Gerhard "Email Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.06.27

Comment: I deleted a post where I had written something trivial (case p prime, misread the question). I don't think this problem can be finished by elementary methods, though. It would amount to proving an effective version of Zsigmondy's theorem (where there is a Zsigmondy prime of exponent 1), which is at least as hard as FLT...

Comment: "It would amount to proving an effective version of Zsigmondy's theorem (where there is a Zsigmondy prime of exponent 1), which is at least as hard as FLT..." 

So has Mike got it right there?

Comment: Yes, I believe there are no simpler approaches...

Comment: Thank you (as always) for your insights, Gjergji.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.06.27 